# Differences between OFDM, OFDMA and SC-FDMA?

Tags: 3g, ofdm

I understand that -

1. multiple user scenarios lead to OFDMA
2. in SD-FDMA at any point of time, all subcarriers carry the same symbol.

What I want is to understand on what exactly differentiates them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-carrier_FDMA  for **SC-FDMA**

Comment: I went through the wiki articles of each of them, but didn't find a point-to-point comparison of them.